# When trying to read File while testing on Android Studio the application just closes

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, testing

So I've been working on an App that tells you random topics to talk about.
I try to read in a File and show a Text with a random Topic that was on the File.
My code to do this is here:

```
package com.example.nosir;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Random;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String mPath = "example.txt";
    private QuoteBank mQuoteBank;
    private List<String> mLines;
    Random random = new Random();

    TextView text1;
    String theTopic;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

        mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
        mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPath);
        for (String string : mLines)
            Log.d(TAG, string);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                text1.setText(mLines.get(random.nextInt(mLines.size())));
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    }


}
```

```
package com.example.nosir;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuoteBank {

    private Context mContext;

    public QuoteBank(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public List<String> readLine(String path) {
        List<String> mLines = new ArrayList<>();

        AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream is = am.open(path);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                mLines.add(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mLines;
    }
}
```

But when I press the button to show the random Text, my application just closes and does nothing.
I'm testing on a OnePlus6.
I really don't know what's the issue.
I hope that somebody can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if I change "text1.setText(mLines.get(random.nextInt(mLines.size())));" to "text1.setText(mLines.toString());" it doesn't close the app, but just displays "[]"

Comment: I recommend running the application through the debugger, that way when the close / crash occurs you can see which line causes the fault. From the fact it crashes on the button press its most likely ```text1.setText(mLines.get(random.nextInt(mLines.size())));``` So check example.txt exists and you can read from your class.

Comment: close means i think it crashes check your logcat you will get the reason or post the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the fast replies. I found a way to do it on my own an it's much shorter and better than the old code.
Here is the code, if anyone is interested:

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

    Button b_read;
    TextView tv_text;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b_read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_read);

        tv_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

        b_read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = "";
                String words[] = null;
                int x = (int) (Math.random()*1556 + 1);
                try{
                    InputStream is = getAssets().open("Themen.txt");
                    int size = is.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    is.read(buffer);
                    is.close();
                    text = new String(buffer);
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\n");
                    words = pattern.split(text);
                } catch (IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                tv_text.setText(words[x]);
            }

        });


    }


}
```